# VBA Excel-Access 3251 Runtime error

Tags: vba, excel, ms-access-2007, excel-2007

I currently use Microsoft Office 2007 and have linked an Access 2007 Database to Excel 2007 Database.  So far so good.  I can update the Access Database and it shows automatically in the Excel file.  Here is where I have the problem.

When I try to update an Access Database from within Excel; I keep getting the runtime 3251 Error. =>runtime error now resolved but NEW issue regarding a NULL value when im trying to add data?

```
Sub ADODBExcelToAccess()
'Collecting data from the
    Dim cn As ADODB.Connection, rs As ADODB.Recordset, r As Long

    '---NOTE: Sheet is set to auto refresh data from the database on loading---

    ' connect to the Access database
    Set cn = New ADODB.Connection
    cn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; " & _
            "Data Source=" & Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\linktest.accdb;"

    ' open a recordset (i.e. a table)
    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset

    rs.Open "linktest", cn, adOpenKeyset, adLockOptimistic, adCmdTable

    ' all records in a table
    For i = 4 To 16
        x = 0

        Do While Len(Range("K" & i).Offset(0, x).Formula) > 0
            With rs
                'create a new record
                .AddNew
                .Fields("ID") = Range("A1" & i).Value
                .Fields("PriceID") = Range("B1").Value
                .Fields("ProductCode") = Range("C1").Value
                .Fields("Price") = Range("D1" & i).Value
                .Fields("CurrencyType") = Range("E1").Value
                .Fields("Type") = Range("F1").Value
                .Fields("Production") = Range("G1" & i).Value
                .Fields("Quantity") = Range("H1" & i).Value
                .Fields("Details") = Range("I1" & i).Value
                .Fields("DateUpdated") = Range("J1" & i).Value
                .Fields("Setup") = Range("K1" & i).Value

                ' stores the new record
                .Update

            End With
            x = x + 1
        Loop
    Next i
    rs.Close
    Set rs = Nothing
    cn.Close
    Set cn = Nothing
End Sub
```

The current reference library that I'm using is Active X Data Objects 2.1 Library.

Comment: What line is error? Is it on the update?

Comment: Sorry its on the ".addNew" or at least thats the line that becomes highlighted

The error is the 3251 error and it states

"Current Recordset does not support Updating.  This may be a limitation of the provider, or of the selected locktype"

Comment: I hate ado with access databases. But if you don't want to use DAO try opening with adoopendynamic instead of keyset. Check RS.updatable property right after .open to make sure you recorded can be updated. Is ID a primary key field?

Comment: ADO version 2.1 is really out of date (it seems to have been released in the late 1990s). Try referencing version 2.8 instead

Comment: You might need to add ";Persist Security Info" to your connection string... Or you could always try DAO

Comment: @dbmitch - yes the ID is a primary key field should i remove this? ... will try using the adoopendynamic thanks

Comment: @barrowc - will try that now thanks

Comment: No. You need primary key in ado recordsetr updates

Comment: Halfway there! Thank you to everyone who has made suggestions / edits so far.

I went into the connections in Excel and altered the ShareDeny and changed it to 
    Mode=Share Deny None

Also some minor alterations to the code which I have show n the main code on the question.  However now i get an really random error saying im trying to assign a Null value?

Comment: RESOLVED NULL (commented the auto field)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ANSWER

OK so the issue was I was getting a runtime error when trying to "Add" a new record to a database with

```
Do While Len(Range("K" & i).Offset(0, x).Formula) > 0
        With rs
            'create a new record
            .AddNew
            .Fields("ID") = Range("A1" & i).Value ...
```

This was so I could save the records from an Excel Spreadsheet into an Access Database (both office 2007).

I opened the connections option in Excel slected the properties of my connection and changed the mode to the following ";Mode=Share Deny None!"

So now my connection string looks like this:

```
Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;User ID=Admin;Data
Source=C:\linktest.accdb;Mode=Share Deny None;Extended Properties="";
Jet OLEDB:System database="";
Jet OLEDB:Registry Path="";Jet OLEDB:Engine Type=6;
Jet OLEDB:Database Locking Mode=1;Jet OLEDB:Global Partial Bulk Ops=2;
Jet OLEDB:Global Bulk Transactions=1;Jet OLEDB:
New Database Password="";Jet OLEDB:Create System Database=False;
Jet OLEDB:Encrypt Database=False;Jet OLEDB:Don't Copy Locale on Compact=False;
Jet OLEDB:Compact Without Replica Repair=False;
Jet OLEDB:SFP=False;Jet OLEDB:Support Complex Data=False
```

I then had a second issue when i returned an error stating that the data I was trying to return gave a "NULL" value.  This was because I was trying to save data t the primary key in the database which returned the error.

I simply commented out this line and this resolved this issue.

I also changed the reference to 
Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 6.1 Library

Answer (score 1):

Thought I'd show a DAO alternative - it's the default db method now with the newer Access versions. As I noted in the code it requires a reference to `Microsoft Office 14.0 Access database engine Object Library` or whatever version you have on your system now.

```
Option Explicit

Sub DAOExcelToAccess()
    ' Requires Reference To
    ' Microsoft Office 14.0 Access database engine Object Library

    Dim db      As DAO.Database
    Dim rs      As DAO.Recordset
    Dim strFile As String
    Dim i       As Integer
    Dim x       As Integer

    strFile = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\linktest.accdb"
    Set db = DBEngine.OpenDatabase(strFile)
    Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("linktest", dbOpenDynaset)
    With rs
        For i = 4 To 16
            x = 0

            ' repeat until first empty cell in column A
            Range("A2").Activate

            'create a new record
            .AddNew
            ' Remove ID if it is AutoIncrement field
            ' .Fields("ID") = Range("A1" & i).Value
            .Fields("Area") = "Test" & i
            .Fields("ProductCode") = Range("C1").Value
            .Fields("Price") = Range("D1" & i).Value
            .Fields("CurrencyType") = Range("E1").Value
            .Fields("Type") = Range("F1").Value
            .Fields("Production") = Range("G1" & i).Value
            .Fields("Quantity") = Range("H1" & i).Value
            .Fields("Details") = Range("I1" & i).Value
            .Fields("DateUpdated") = Range("J1" & i).Value
            .Fields("Setup") = Range("K1" & i).Value

            ' stores the new record
            .Update

             x = x + 1
        Next i

        .Close
    End With
End Sub
```